# Run an action for every item in collection, one by one WITH A PAUSE

Tags: c#, linq, task

I need to execute a task for each item in a collection, one by one (not in parallel) **with a pause** to prevent DB-server heat. Here's a method I wrote:

```
public static Task ForEachWithPause<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumeration, Action<T> action, int milliseconds)
{
    return Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        foreach (T item in enumeration)
        {
            action(item);
            await Task.Delay(milliseconds);
        }
    });
}

//usage
intCollection..ForEachWithPause(integer =>
    {
        //do something with integer
    }, 500);
```

Anyone sees any problem with it? I'm very new to tasks and `async`

Comment: Looks fine, but I would not put it into production =) It is just strange that you trying to avoid "DB heat" by implementing throttling on client, rather than do it on server. You basically spreading this load, not avoiding it. Just write optimal one-call query for all integers or process them in batches.

Comment: @eocron thanks!
PS. Well, in RL it's way more complicated than integers. Super complicated business-logic, and we need to add "bulk-actions" to the app.